# What is the difference between "clearance" and "sale"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

I want to understand the difference between *clearance* and *sale*. So are these words synonyms or not? E.g.

> - Receive 60–90% off CookiesKids Clearance from Cookie's Kids.
> - Receive 50–85% off After Holiday Sale Items from Woodwind & Brasswind.

Comment: Both advertise sales. A _clearance sale_ is usually intended to "clear the shelves of the sale items" because the store will no longer sell them. A normal sale is just a discount (usually for a specified length of time) and is intended only to increase sales of the sale items, which the store may or may not continue to sell (new models might be coming in soon, or a new shipment might be coming, so it's necessary to sell more of these items to reduce stock on hand).

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Littleshot. What did you find when you looked in the dictionary? (You did check the dictionary first, didn't you?) Why are the dictionary definitions insufficient to remove your confusion? (Dictionary.com: [4. the disposal of merchandise at reduced prices to make room for new goods](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clearance?s=t) vs. [4. a special disposal of goods, as at reduced prices](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sale?s=t) makes it clear to me that the difference lies in the making room for new goods.)

Comment: Where do your doubts come from?

All clearances are sales; not all sales are clearances.

Similarly all dogs (except those injured) have four feet but by no means all four-footed creatures are dogs…

Answer (score 4):

*Clearance* is most often used (but not exclusively) when a shop wants to *clear* a particular stock line. In your example this would be *CookiesKids*. The reasons vary, but most often because they're not stocking that line any more or they simply want to clear old remaining stock before the new season stock arrives.

*Sale* is most often used when referring to multiple branded stock items or more than one type of item from the same brand. In your example this applies to multiple brands or items from the shop or brand Woodwind & Brasswind.

Comment: *Sale* is used whenever anything is temporarily offered at a discounted price- I think it's overcomplicated to bring *multiple branded stock* items into it.

Comment: @Jim I would tend to agree. However, I'm trying to make a distinction between the words *clearance* and *sale* as used in the OP's two examples. In those two examples *clearance* clearly refers to a specific brand, hence my distinction using brands. To say a *sale is whenever anything is temporarily discounted* does not help explain the difference between the two examples.

Comment: Clearance does not need to be a specific brand.  A store may clearance all of its furniture offerings if it has decided to get out of the furniture business.  The distinction is that *clearance* is a sale *for the purposes of getting rid of inventory* whereas a plain *sale* could be for other purposes as well- for example to draw customers into the store.

Comment: @Jim I never said it did :) I think I said that quite clearly and without ambiguity in my answer. I believe you are now being unnecessarily **pedantic**.

Comment: I guess it was when you said "*clearance clearly refers to a specific brand, hence my distinction using brands*" that threw me.

Comment: @spiceyokooko I would be inclined to disagree that it doesn't explain the difference. For example, all clearances are sales, but not all sales are clearances. A sale is, as Jim is implying clearly, when an item is offered temporarily at a discount price. A clearance is, then, a specific sale where the item is being offered temporarily at a discount price, as the item(s) in question may or may not be offered again, or because simply the stock needs to clear for new inventory.

Answer (score 3):

A clearance is a sale (event in which a large number of items are discounted) in which the vendor intends to get rid of all remaining stock (whether before new stock, or before closing down). A sale may not necessarily cover this case.

Answer (score 3):

Walmart informed me tonight that "Clearance" is not a sale ... just reducing the merchandise. They had a giant "Clearance" sign over a rack of clothes and NOTHING was marked down.  All the stickers had the everyday price. I asked the sale lady, the manager of that department and the store's assistant manager why the merchandise had just the everyday price and not a clearance price and that's when she informed me that "Clearance" did not mean they were on sale.

Answer (score 1):

Clearance: clearing out either permanently or to get new stock in

Sale: lower the price for a period of time

Comment: This doesn't add anything new to the answers. Please consider answering question that have not already been adequately answered before posting on old questions that have.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb you might look forward to deeper discounts/better price-offs at a clearance sale.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, autoresponder. Why do you believe a clearance sale has better prices? What is your source for this belief?

Comment: Yep. Caveat emptor. ['Fake' Sales Trick Customers at Major Stores, Study Says](https://www.nbcnews.com/business/consumer/fake-sales-trick-customers-major-stores-study-says-n366676)

Answer (score -1):

Items that are old and available in the store are put on clearance 
Retailers put sale on expensive  items  available in the store.

Comment: Hi Nic, welcome to English Language & Usage. Note that this site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: an answer is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct* - preferably by quoting a reference (e.g. dictionary definition) hyperlinked to the source. You can [edit] your post to add this detail; for further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Answer (score -3):

Both is to make transaction
Clereance is getting rid of old items
Sale is to bring in Customers

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Your answer here has been flagged by the system for being short and the system thinks it might be "low quality". It’s correct in my opinion, but it doesn’t add anything over existing answers on an old question. It's better to upvote existing answers if you agree with them.